# get Image's UIBezierPath without transparent area

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, uiview, uibezierpath

I have a transparent image with the shape like this. Can we extract the `UIBezierPath` of this image? For example, I can draw a hexagon myself in my `UIView` class, but I couldn't get the `UIBezierPath` of this shape.

[image]

orginal Image : [image: orjinalImage]

```swift
class FreeShapeView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.clear(rect)
      
        context?.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
        context?.setShouldAntialias(true)
        context?.setLineJoin(CGLineJoin.round)
        
        let edge: CGFloat = 5.9/2

        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: edge))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - edge, y: rect.height/3))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - edge, y: rect.height/3*2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height - edge))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: edge, y: rect.height/3*2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: edge, y: rect.height/3))
        
        path.close()
        context?.addPath(path.cgPath)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

My Objective C code for OpenCV

```
      + (UIBezierPath *)removeTransparentAreaAndFindContours:(UIImage *)image {
    // Convert UIImage to cv::Mat
   
    cv::Mat cvImage = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];


    // Convert image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayscaleImage;
    cv::cvtColor(cvImage, grayscaleImage, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    // Apply threshold to create binary image
    cv::Mat binaryImage;
    cv::threshold(grayscaleImage, binaryImage, 1, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    // Find contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(binaryImage, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Create a UIBezierPath from the contours
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        const std::vector<cv::Point> &contour = contours[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < contour.size(); j++) {
            const cv::Point &point = contour[j];
            CGPoint cgPoint = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y);
            if (j == 0) {
                [bezierPath moveToPoint:cgPoint];
            } else {
                [bezierPath addLineToPoint:cgPoint];
            }
        }
        [bezierPath closePath];
    }

    return bezierPath;
}

+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = image.size.height;
    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per channel, 4 channels (RGBA)

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data, cols, rows, 8, cvMat.step[0], colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    return cvMat;
}
```

I get some result like this .

```
Element 1: Type = MoveToPoint, Points = (0.0, 0.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 2: Type = AddLineToPoint, Points = (0.0, 794.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 3: Type = AddLineToPoint, Points = (619.0, 794.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 4: Type = AddLineToPoint, Points = (620.0, 795.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 5: Type = AddLineToPoint, Points = (620.0, 1270.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 6: Type = AddLineToPoint, Points = (1998.0, 1270.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 7: Type = AddLineToPoint, Points = (1998.0, 0.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0) 
Element 8: Type = CloseSubpath, Points = (1998.0, 0.0) (6.9370081173396e-310, 0.0)
```

testing code is :

```
 path = UIBezierPath()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0.0 , y:794.0 ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:619.0 , y:794.0 ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 620.0, y: 795.0 ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:620.0 , y:1270.0 ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1998.0, y:1270.0 ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:1998.0 , y: 0.0))
        
        path.close()
        context?.addPath(path.cgPath)
```

but it's draw like that :

[image]

what am i doing wrong ? thanks

Comment: If you have a **simple** image, such as the one you posted, you *could* use a flood-fill algorithm and track the contiguous alpha or non-alpha pixels. Would likely be slow, unless you know ahead of time "about what to expect." Otherwise, you might want to look at `VNDetectContoursRequest` / `VNContoursObservation`

Comment: thank you.I gonna look them . I am using now OpenCV but I didn't success it . I gonna edit to question now

Comment: OK - you got the path of the "shape" from your image... What is your question?

Comment: Are you sure that I get shape of image with this result? But I can’t draw in uiview class. Today worked hard maybe I lost something

Comment: This is the shape I get using those points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlWSp.png

Comment: Please can you share your drawing codes? Thank you

Comment: I just added test code too. I edited question. you can see there. but I get different shape. if it's possible can you add your source code to drive or some link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **original image** size is `5997 x 3811`.

The coordinates generated give you a `UIBezierPath` with a bounding box size of `1998.0 x 1270.0`. I don't use `OpenCV`, but it appears to be based on a `@3x` device scale -- so you are getting coordinates in **points** not **pixels**.

In any case, if you simply try to draw a `1998.0 x 1270.0` path in, for example, a `300 x 300` view, you will only see the top-left part of the path.

If you scale the path to fit the view, you'll see the whole path:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0.0 , y:794.0 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:619.0 , y:794.0 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 620.0, y: 795.0 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:620.0 , y:1270.0 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1998.0, y:1270.0 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:1998.0 , y: 0.0))
    
    path.close()

    let scale: CGFloat = bounds.width / path.bounds.width
    
    let tr = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    path.apply(tr)
```